# Fragment onCreateView called twice inside Tab (ActionBar) when rotating the phone

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

When I rotate the phone, this method gets called twice.. and actually the second time savedInstanceState is null... Is this a normal behavior?

Answer (score -2):

When the device orientation changes the activity is completely recreated, yes this is normal behaviour. Use saved instance to hold onto any content data that you don't wish to requery, such as a remote service call or database call. That way you can save the users data costs and get faster recreation of the page.

Comment: I don't think it is normal to call onCreateView two times. I am checking how I attach and detach the fragment to the tab because I think the problem is there... hopefully.

Comment: just a thought, your not creating the fragment class in xml and in code?

Comment: No, and I just found the mistake. The example FragmentTabs.java from the API examples detaches the Fragment and attaches it back again in onTabSelected. That's causing the two calls. If the fragment is already attached I don't understand why they detach it first...

Comment: I assume it gets detached to save on resources, device can free up the memory and reclaim it when needed. Makes sense really to only hold onto it if it is being used.